# Javascript callback function + AJAX.done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a huge problem with Javascript.

There is a Javascript API:

```
function GetData(par1,par2,par3, callback){
  var querystr = "something";
  $.ajax({
    url: querystr,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    statusCode: 
    {
      404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    },
      403:function() {
      window.location = IP_address;
    }
  }
  }).done(function(input){
    //[some other processing, it is also works]
    callback(output);
  });

GetData(1,2,3,function(output){
  //get some other local specific processing
});
```

Now this option somewhere runs well, don't throw any error. In Firefox, simply can't enter into the callback function, IE11 drops error : Function expected. Why?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Also, learn how to property comment your code in JS using `//` to escape them — otherwise it's hard for us to know whether is a genuine error, or simply bad formatting.

Comment: Just one thought: is there nothing in the output variable, it can be a problem?

Comment: It *potentially* can, but it all boils down to how `callback()` is defined, and if it has pre-existing safeguards in place that uses/fallbacks to a default value if `output` is undefined.

Comment: Exactly what line of code does IE show an error on and exactly what does the error message say.  These details are very important.

Comment: The IE drops this error: "Function Expected", ant points to the callback(output);

Comment: I think we would need to see all the code in this area (without leaving out parts) because the error you're describing does not make sense unless there is something else wrong in the area that we cannot see.

Comment: I know you just edited the code, but the bracing is still messed up (the GetData function has no closing brace and there's an errant closing brace before `.done()`).  We can't tell what the real errors are when you post non-functioning code full of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the real problem, but your syntax is wrong. You forgot a parenthesis :

```
.done(function(input){
    // [some other processing, it is also works]
    callback(output);
}); // <--- you forgot this one
```

Some browsers try to correct errors in codes (like firefox and chrome). IE is very strict and stop at every syntax error.

Comment: This must be a typo in the question, not in the real code because this would not work in any browser.

Comment: No sorry, I made a mistake in the post, in my code this syntax is correct.